# how to detect extension installed on firefox 4.6 ubuntu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ubuntu, firefox

I installed jsprintsetup extension on Firefox version 4.6 on my laptop with ubuntu os . how to check firefox extensions installed. I have searched google but have not yet found the right way

Comment: Check the URL `about:addons`. That's not a programming question.

Comment: so I want to print a document's based on the extension that has been installed . extensinya if not installed then it will be directed to use print javascript

Comment: Ok I see, it's programming. +1 Please add more info *where* you want to check. On a JavaScript website, from within an addon...

Answer (score 1):

From https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/

> Extension creates global object called `jsPrintSetup`.

You can check if this object exists or not.

```
if ( jsPrintSetup ) {
    alert('JS Print Setup Extension is installed');
}
else {
    alert('JS Print Setup Extension is NOT installed');
}
```

This worked for me on Firefox **46**

Comment: not worked for me. are you using ubuntu or windows os?

Comment: Firefox 46 on Ubuntu 14.04. How are you executing this ? Is this in your own extension or javascript embedded in a html page ?

Comment: Corrected my answer. It was missing a `}`

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 14.04 but when i'm running your script show the blank page

Comment: How are you running the script ?

Comment: copy paste and save .php and then running on localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112104/discussion-between-mad-piranha-and-faizal-3696).

Comment: @faizal 3696, If this answer has solved your question then please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)